# Implement UnionFind with weighted Quick Union and Path Compression

Tags: java

I try to implement UnionFind with weighted quick Union and Path Compression.  I am not sure where I did it wrong though.  Here are my codes.

I think it goes wrong at the union function but I passed my JUnit tests so I am not sure.  I tried to look for the answer online but they all use different variables.  I try to use only 1 int[] array

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class UnionFind {
public int[] array; // the init array

/* Creates a UnionFind data structure holding N vertices. Initially, all
   vertices are in disjoint sets. */
public UnionFind(int N) {
    array = new int[N];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < N; i++) {
        array[i] = -1;
    }
}

/* Returns the size of the set V belongs to. */
public int sizeOf(int v) {
    if(array[v] < 0){
        return - array[v];
    } else {
        int findNeg = array[v];
        while(findNeg > 0) {
            findNeg = array[findNeg];
        }
        return -findNeg;
    }
}

/* Returns the parent of V. If V is the root of a tree, returns the
   negative size of the tree for which V is the root. */
public int parent(int v) {
    if(array[v] > 0){
        return array[v];
    } else {
        return -sizeOf(v);
    }
}

/* Returns true if nodes V1 and V2 are connected. */
public boolean connected(int v1, int v2) {
    return find(v1) == find(v2);
}

/* Returns the root of the set V belongs to. Path-compression is employed
   allowing for fast search-time. If invalid vertices are passed into this
   function, throw an IllegalArgumentException. */
public int find(int v) {
   if(v < 0) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException ("vertices can not be less than 0");
   }
   if (v > array.length){
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Out of Bound, vertices can not be longer than array");
   }
   if(array[v] < 0){
       return v;
   } else {
       int findNeg = v;
       ArrayList<Integer> children = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       while (array[findNeg] > 0) {
           children.add(findNeg);
           findNeg = array[findNeg];
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
           array[children.get(i)]= findNeg;
       }
       return findNeg;
   }

}

/* Connects two elements V1 and V2 together. V1 and V2 can be any element,
   and a union-by-size heuristic is used. If the sizes of the sets are
   equal, tie break by connecting V1's root to V2's root. Union-ing a vertex
   with itself or vertices that are already connected should not change the
   structure. */
public void union(int v1, int v2) {
    if(sizeOf(v1) == sizeOf(v2)) {
        array[find(v1)] += (-sizeOf(v2));
        array[find(v2)] = find(v1);
        array[v2] = find(v1);
    } else if (sizeOf(v1) > sizeOf(v2)){
        array[find(v1)] += (-sizeOf(v2));
        array[v2] = find(v1);
    } else {
        array[find(v2)] += (-sizeOf(v1));
        array[v1] = find(v2);
    }

}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Too much code. Please trim this down to a MCVE. Also clarify what your input is, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: @xing what's the purpose of `array[find(v1)] += (-sizeOf(v2));` and `array[find(v2)] += (-sizeOf(v1));` ? the array element must contain the index of its immediate parent, so why do you assign the "tree size" to it?

Comment: seems that "sizeOf" is not even a size, does it always return 1? it recurses back to root until reaching -1, then negates it and returns 1, so what's its purpose then?

Comment: @mangusta I tried to find the root and then increase the size of that branch.  Array[i] gives me the value of a parent.  If that parent happens to be the root, array[i] stores the negative of size

Comment: Yes, sizeOf returns the size of the branch

Comment: I found out eventually. I did not follow this "If the sizes of the sets are
   equal, tie break by connecting V1's root to V2's root."